# Не запускается телеграмм бот на Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, telegram-bot, spring-boot

Делал по примеру телеграмм бота, но он у меня не запускается. хотя делал 1 в 1...
Вот на гитхабе мой бот - https://github.com/DeadSidert/commybot1

Выдает кучу ошибок на подобии этой:

```html
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368) [spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.createQuery(Unknown Source) [na:na]
 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) [spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) [spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Какие то проблемы с базой данных - вы ее создали? Юзера и пароли правильно прописаны?

Comment: @НикитаКочнев приведи полный  лог ошибки